# c++11: short notation for pow?

Tags: c++, c++11

I need paste huge formula into my c++11 code.
This formula contains numerous things like double type to power of integer:
[image: formula]

It is boring to write:

```
pow(sin(B), 6) + ... pow(sin(C), 4) + ....
```

20 times

The best thing will be overload operator^ for double and int,
but as I understand it is not possible for C++11. And in formula like this:

```
z0^2 * (something)
```

according to precedence of operators it would be like this:

```
z0 ^ (2 * (something))
```

and this is not what I want.

So is it possible using some trick to approximate math notation for x to power of y with C++ code?

Possible toools are: c++11 and boost.

**Update:**

About support code with such math notation instead of C++.

Ideal solution as I see would be like:

```
const double result = (latex_mode
    (sin(B_0))^6(a + b)
    latex_mode_end)
    (B_0, a, b);
```

where latex_mode support small subset of LaTex language without ambiguity.
1)All programmers that touch this code have mathematical background, so they read latex without problem
2)Formula can be copy/paste from article without any modification,
so it will reduce typo errors.

Comment: No, and this is a horrible idea.  Just suck it up and use the language.

Comment: Is it possible? Yes. Should you do it? Everybody (including me) is gonna tell you no.

Comment: Don't listen to them and do it!!

Comment: Would be faster to copy paste the `pow` than to write the operator overload code

Comment: @Mysticial Can someone explain *why not?* Or point to somewhere where it is explained?

Comment: @becko: Because it's absurdly difficult, error prone, and confuses every who looks at your code next year, including yourself.

Comment: You would be better off writing code to generate the C++ code. Or look into your IDE/text editor's capabilities.

Comment: @becko Quite often, when you try turn an apple into an orange, it doesn't work too well. The person reading the code is gonna be expecting the `^` to be xor and be confused as hell until (s)he discovers the overload.

Comment: I think the only binary operators with higher precedence than `*` are `[]` and `()`.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Sure, except `.*`, `->*`, `.`, `->`, `::` ;)

Comment: `double sinpow(double B, double e) {return pow(sin(B,e));}  var v = sinpow(B,6) + sinpow(C,4) + ...;`

Comment: @Oguk Brainfart sorry (OP confused me by using `^` for exponent in code formatting block - case in point!)

Comment: @MooingDuck Or do the same thing with a lambda function, if it's only needed locally, i.e. `auto sp = [](double a, double b){return pow(sin(a),b);};` and then use `sp(B,6)`.

Comment: Long formulas can be easily produced with Mathematica by using the C output format.

Answer (score 5):

No, you can't do it. At least, you shouldn't. But it can be simplified otherwise. If your formula can be described as [image]
 then you can make table of pairs (a,b) and write code which itself will do it. For example:

```
  vector<pair<unsigned, unsigned>> table = {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}};
  unsigned sum = 0; 
  for(const auto& x : table)
    sum += pow(get<0>(x), get<1>(x));
```

---

Inspired by a @5gon12eder's comment I wrote a function:

```
template <typename Input, typename Output = unsigned>
Output powers(std::initializer_list<Input> args) {
  Output result = 0;
  for(const auto x : args)
   result += pow(std::get<0>(x), std::get<1>(x));
  return result;
 }
```

You need additional (standard) library:

1. [#tuple](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/tuple)
2. [#initializer_list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/initializer_list)

Example of use:

```
std::pair<unsigned, unsigned> a{1,2}, b{2,3};
std::cout << powers({a, b, {3, 4}, {4,5}}) << '\n';
```

That prints `1114` and [it's correct](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%202%5E3%203%5E4%204%5E5).

---

Referring to edit part, I can suggest write a function receiving string and parsing. But it will be much slower than the above method.
Finally, you can write to the authors of your compiler.

**Edit**:
With C++14 new possibilities appeared. You can make constexpr functions with for, variables etc. So it is easier to create compile-time parser. I still recommend solution from original part of post, cause it will be little bit messy, but it will do what you want in compile-time.

String to int example:

```
#include <iostream>


template<size_t N>
constexpr uint32_t to_int(const char (&input)[N]) { // Pass by reference
    uint32_t result = 0;
    for(uint32_t i = 0; i < N && input[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
        result *= 10;
        result += input[i] - '0';
    }

    return result;
}

constexpr uint32_t value = to_int("123427");

enum { __force_compile_time_computing = value };

int main() {
    std::cout << value << std::endl;
}
```

Prints:

```
~ $ g++ -std=c++14 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors example.cpp 
~ $ ./a.out 
123427
~ $
```

Obviously it will be harder to make parser. Probably the best way to do it is to create constexpr class Operation with two constructors `Operation(operation, operation)` and `Operation(value)` and to create  calculation tree in compile time (if you have variables in your string).

---

If you don't want to do whole this job, and you can accept other program/language semantic, then you can realize easy run-time solution. Create new thread which calls R/mathematica/{something else} and send input string to it. After calculation resend value to main program.
If you want some hint, probably using [std::future](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future) will be convenient.

Comment: +1 And you can even make this a variadric template if you want and then elegantly write `sum_sine_powers({B, 6}, {C, 4}, ...)`.  It doesn't really save you *a lot* of typing but at the very least, it will make you look cool in front of your friends.

Answer (score 3):

Just for the record, this is what [Bjarne Stroustrup says about it](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#overload-operator):

> **Can I define my own operators?**
>
> Sorry, no. The possibility has been considered several times, but each time I/we decided that the likely problems outweighed the likely benefits.
>
> It's not a language-technical problem. Even when I first considerd it in 1983, I knew how it could be implemented. However, my experience has been that when we go beyond the most trivial examples people seem to have subtlely different opinions of “the obvious” meaning of uses of an operator. A classical example is `a**b**c`. Assume that `**` has been made to mean exponentiation. Now should `a**b**c` mean `(a**b)**c` or `a**(b**c)`? I thought the answer was obvious and my friends agreed – and then we found that we didn't agree on which resolution was the obvious one. My conjecture is that such problems would lead to subtle bugs.

Interestingly, it is exactly the operator you are missing.  Well, this is not that much a coincidence since many people are missing a built-in exponentiation operator.  Especially those who know Fortran or Python (two languages otherwise rarely mentioned together).

Comment: I never missed the ability of invent one's own operator in C++, as in some other language. C++ is such a complicated beast as it is. It looks innocent at first. But once you get to know it better, all kinds of hell can break unless one learns to discipline himself. I can't imagine how life will be complicated if add that into the mix

Comment: @YanZhou inventing your own operator symbols is no more complicated than inventing your own identifiers.